# Problema con "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" al cargar recurso en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet

Estoy enfrentando un problema al cargar un recurso en mi aplicación web JavaScript. La consola muestra el error `"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"`. Este error parece estar afectando la conexión a un recurso externo, pero no estoy seguro de cómo solucionarlo.

**He verificado mi conexión a internet y otras partes de mi código**, pero aún no puedo resolver este problema. ¿Alguien ha experimentado esto antes o tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo abordar este error?

Comment: Esto puede ser causado por muchas cosas, estás intentando acceder a un recurso protegido, no tienes acceso a ese recurso, estás detrás de un firewall que no te permite acceso, tiene mala la ubicación del recurso, etc etc